# can not publish any page in edit mode

Tags: php, concrete5, concrete5-8.x

Could you please tell me how to publish pages after clicking edit button (left top menu) mode in cocrete5 cms version 5.8.1.0 not using compose button?
I can't publish any page clicking edit button in top left corner, editing it and clicking edit button again.
Publish Changes Button is disabled and there is message:
 "The field Page Thumbnail is required."
But I can publish using compose menu (next to edit in left top corner).
What's the cause of this problem? Is it concrete5 bug?

It looks like it allows to publish if I comment out lines in check for publishinh method. But I can't still understand the cause of issue and how to fix it.

```
class CheckIn extends BackendInterfacePageController
{
    protected $viewPath = '/panels/page/check_in';
    // we need this extra because this controller gets called by another page
    // and that page needs to know how to submit it.
    protected $controllerActionPath = '/ccm/system/panels/page/check_in';

    public function canAccess()
    {
        return $this->permissions->canApprovePageVersions() || $this->permissions->canEditPageContents();
    }

    public function on_start()
    {
        parent::on_start();
        if ($this->page) {
            $v = CollectionVersion::get($this->page, "RECENT");

            $this->set('publishDate', $v->getPublishDate());
            $this->set('publishErrors', $this->checkForPublishing());
        }
    }

    protected function checkForPublishing()
    {
        $c = $this->page;
        // verify this page type has all the items necessary to be approved.
        $e = Loader::helper('validation/error');
        if ($c->isPageDraft()) {
            if (!$c->getPageDraftTargetParentPageID()) {
                $e->add(t('You haven\'t chosen where to publish this page.'));
            }
        }
        $pagetype = $c->getPageTypeObject();
//        if (is_object($pagetype)) {
//            $validator = $pagetype->getPageTypeValidatorObject();
//            $e->add($validator->validatePublishDraftRequest($c));
//        }

        if ($c->isPageDraft() && !$e->has()) {
            $targetParentID = $c->getPageDraftTargetParentPageID();
            if ($targetParentID) {
                $tp = Page::getByID($targetParentID, 'ACTIVE');
                $pp = new Permissions($tp);
                if (!is_object($tp) || $tp->isError()) {
                    $e->add(t('Invalid target page.'));
                } else {
                    if (!$pp->canAddSubCollection($pagetype)) {
                        $e->add(
                            t(
                                'You do not have permissions to add a page of this type in the selected location.'
                            )
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $e;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all? 'The field Page Thumbnail is required.' Did you actually add a thumbnail?
Basically you can't submit a form without filling in all the required fields.

Or did you and still got the error?

Comment: As far as I can judge there is thumbnail. I can not publish any page in edit mode but I can publish on composer page.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue overriding file:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Attribute\ImageFile;

use Loader;
use Core;

class Controller extends \Concrete\Attribute\ImageFile\Controller
{
    public function validateValue()
    {
        $f = $this->getAttributeValue()->getValue();

        if (is_object($f)) {
            return true;
        }

        $e = Core::make('helper/validation/error');
        $e->add(t('You must specify a valid file for %s', $this->attributeKey->getAttributeKeyDisplayName()));

        return $e;
    }
}
```